# Error on fragment onCreateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I caught `Shut Down VM` when try open `Fragment` in `onCreateView()`method.
This is code from fragment:

```
public class EconomyPageFragment extends Fragment {

     public EconomyPageFragment() {}

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_economy_page, container, false);
        return view;
   }
}
```

And this xml-layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

**UPD** - add some lines from `gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

If I comment `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.../>` all work.

Comment: Did you add the support library in your module gradle file?

Comment: @LuisMiguelSierra done